# class not found in php

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I have a PHP project structured as:

```
--root
 |--dr1
 |   |---dr2
 |        |--testclass.php
 |--start.php
 |--bootstrap.php
```

The testclass.php contains:

```
 namespace dr1\dr2;

 class testclass { 
     ... 
 }
```

The bootstrap.php contains:

```
define('DIR_SEP', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DIR_SEP);

function __autoload($class)
{
    $path = ROOT . str_replace('\\', DIR_SEP, $class);
    $file = $path . '.php';
    if( is_file($file) ) require_once($file);
}

spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
```

and The start.php contains:

```
$class = 'dr1\dr2\testclass.php';
$obj   = new $class();
```

When I run the start.php, I got the message `dr1\dr2\testclass.php` is not found on `start.php` on line 5. I could not figure out why. would anybody help. thanks a lot.

Comment: The class is named `testclass` and not `testclass.php`. So I guess it should be: `$class = 'dr1\dr2\testclass'`.

Comment: your answer works, post it and I will accept. :) thanks.

Comment: wow man i have seen first person who knows the answer but not tried to answer it in answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The autoloader looks correct, so the problem is the Classname `testclass.php`. In you source-file it's just `testclass` without the `.php` - so if you adjust your `$class`-variable like that it should work:

```
$class = 'dr1\dr2\testclass';
$obj   = new $class();
```

Answer (score 1):

To access your class you could do

`$class = new testclass();`

Comment: @aspringaqib all my work with `class();` revolve around that one line to access, my apologies if I was wrong though :)

Comment: nah man i didn't asked the question. But if you answered wrong today then obviously after seeing your mistake you will never answer it wrong! buddy just chill this is only a mistake!